# using python client to view query of a job

Tags: google-bigquery

How do we use the python sdk client to view the query that was submitted to a job with the use of job_id?  I've been browsing the documentation, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Can you post a code sample? How are you submitting the job?

Comment: As in I have a job, which is to run a query by some user (not myself), can I see the query that they are running?

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L699

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [googleapis/google-cloud-python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery) project to find what you are looking for